# Issue in fetching attribute data from image - JQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, clone

I have been trying to  fetch the attribute from images which i have derived from a set of ul based image gallery using clone.

This is the Ul Tag i wanted to clone --

```
<ul class="bannerscollection_zoominout_list">
                    <li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText1" data-bottom-thumb="images/home_bg/infrastructure_s.jpg" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center">
                    <img src="images/home_bg/infrastructure.jpg" width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text"/></li>
                    <li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText2" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" data-bottom-thumb="images/home_bg/library_s.jpg" >
                    <img src="images/home_bg/library.jpg" width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text"/></li>
                    <li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText3" data-bottom-thumb="images/home_bg/bus_facilities_s.jpg" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" >
                    <img src="images/home_bg/bus_facilities.jpg" width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text"/></li>
                    <li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText4" data-bottom-thumb="images/home_bg/canteen_s.jpg" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" >
                    <img src="images/home_bg/canteen.jpg" width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" /></li>
                    <li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_zoominout_photoText5" data-bottom-thumb="images/home_bg/sports_s.jpg" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" >
                    <img src="images/home_bg/sports.jpg" width="2500" height="1570"  alt="Text"/></li>
        </ul>
```

This is the JQuery i stitched up

```
$('.bannerscollection_zoominout_list li').each(function(){

$(this).clone().appendTo('.mobile ul');
$(".mobile ul li").each(function() {
  // first copy the attributes to remove
  // if we don't do this it causes problems
  // iterating over the array we're removing
  // elements from
  var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
    return item.name;
  });

  // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
  var liat = $(this);
  $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    liat.removeAttr(item);
  });
});
});
});
```

I was successful in getting the li and images (from the ul gallery as desired)

This is the HTML Out put of the Clone

```
<div class="mobile">
<ul>
<li>
                    <img width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" src="images/home_bg/infrastructure.jpg"></li><li>
                    <img width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" src="images/home_bg/library.jpg"></li><li>
                    <img width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" src="images/home_bg/bus_facilities.jpg"></li><li>
                    <img width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" src="images/home_bg/canteen.jpg"></li><li>
                    <img width="2500" height="1570" alt="Text" src="images/home_bg/sports.jpg"></li></ul>
</div>
```

but i want to append an additional h1 tag to the cloned ul. I will need to fetch the 'alt attribute text' for my appended h1 tag. I had no success in doing it so.

My final intention is to display the same images in the banner which doesn't fit in tabs and mobiles phones (read:i am using jquery-zoom-in-zoomout image slider)

any help will be much appreciated...

Comment: Where do you want this additional h1 tag? Can you show with some example code of what you want?

Comment: Resolved Made a clumsy mistake :)

Comment: @jonmirch http://jsfiddle.net/verligte/ds99azs8/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final set of code for the above Jquery Code

```
$('.bannerscollection_zoominout_list li').each(function(){

$(this).clone().appendTo('.mobile ul');
$(".mobile ul li").each(function() {
  // first copy the attributes to remove
  // if we don't do this it causes problems
  // iterating over the array we're removing
  // elements from
  var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function(item) {
    return item.name;
  });

  // now use jQuery to remove the attributes
  var liat = $(this);
  $.each(attributes, function(i, item) {
    liat.removeAttr(item);
  });
});
});

var alt = $('.bannerscollection_zoominout_list li').children("img").attr("alt");
$('.mobile ul li').append('<h1>'+alt+'</h1>');

});
```

I tried this out because i found the images shown in the mobile and tablets were not very responsive when using 
[jquery Slider Zoom In/Out Effect Fully Responsive](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-slider-zoom-inout-effect-fully-responsive/2457203) slider or any other full width/parallax sliders. so I hid the  gallery and used this clone function to create a static display. hope someone finds it useful and also make this code better..

Thanks all again :)